# Make BIND use DHCP DNS as backup

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx, bind

I run BIND locally on my OS X machine, to enable wildcard Apache vhosts, which requires setting the DNS server for all network interfaces to 127.0.0.1.

This works great, but means when I am on a network which uses an internal DNS server to route special (i.e. .companyname) URLs to a server on the network, the lookup fails.

I tried adding both 127.0.0.1 and the DHCP provided DNS server, but this doesn't work either.

Is there a way to make BIND use the DHCP DNS server for requests it cannot resolve locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind was not designed for this use-case.  It was designed to be run on a server where the same sysadmin configures it and the DHCP server.  It was not designed to move.

You could hack together a script to change the `forwarders` in Bind every time your DHCP lease was refreshed but I couldn't recommend this.  You will run into caching issues where your `.company` domains are cached as `NXDOMAIN` when they shouldn't be or cached as a real IPs when they shouldn't be.

There may be a specialised caching/resolving mame server that has the functionality you're after built in but Bind isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure `forwarders` to which BIND will forward all requests that it cannot resolve by itself. However, BIND is *always* able to resolve any name for a domain for which it is `authoritative`. If you configure a wildcard record `*.example.com`, you can't make BIND resolve `foo.example.com` from some other DNS server. You would need to configure those records in the zone hosted by your BIND instance.

Comment: The local instance of BIND is only authoritative for `.localhost` domains, so that won't be a problem - it's `.companyname` domains that aren't working. I have done a bit of research on forwarders, but don't know how to set it up to use the DHCP DNS server.

Comment: You can't configure BIND to use forwarders from DHCP. What might work is using a script to [discover](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/dhcp-discover.html) the DNS servers, change the forwarders in your `named.conf` and restart BIND.